# Trying to utilize combination of generic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This is confusing, as I'm getting seemingly contradictive errors.

I'm using generics, constraining `T` to `Something`, then constraining `U` to `AnOperation<Something>`.

I expected that an object `AnOperation<Something>` is from now on considered of type `U`. But, I'm getting errors:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApp1.AnOperation<T>' to 'U'`

That's weird. Well, i tried explicitly casting it to U, then I got this error:

`Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApp1.AnOperation<T>' to 'U'` which also stated `Cast is redundant`

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }

    class MyClass<T, U>
        where T : Something
        where U : AnOperation<Something>
    {
        public U GetAnOperationOfSomething()
        {
            AnOperation<T> anOperation = new AnOperation<T>();

            return anOperation; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApp1.AnOperation<T>' to 'U'

            // return (U)anOperation; // Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApp1.AnOperation<T>' to 'U' also Cast is redundant
        }
    }

    public class Something
    {
    }

    public class AnOperation<T>
        where T : Something
    {
    }

}
```

What's happening here?

Edit: I'm trying to understand what is the problem in the language level, not looking for a workaround on an actual problem.

Comment: What is the point of having an `U` when in the end you use the actual type instead of your template parameter? Your code should be `var anOperation = new U();` with the `new` constraint for `U`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You almost got it right with your constraint, but not quite. You define

```
 where U : AnOperation<Something>
```

But then you create

```
AnOperation<T> anOperation = new AnOperation<T>()
```

That is not the same thing. If you change your constraint to...

```
 where U : AnOperation<T>
```

...you will be fine.

Another problem is that while every `U` is an `AnOperation<T>`, not every `AnOperation<T>` is an `U`. When you declare...

```
public U GetAnOperationOfSomething()
```

...you are making the guarantee that what the method returns is an `U`. `AnOperation<T>` can not satisfy that guarantee.

You are solving this with a typecast to `U`. That is against the purpose of your generic class, since every `U` must be an `AnOperation<T>` or you will get a runtime exception. That makes the whole type parameter `U` unnecessary. What you actually *want* to do is create an `U`. You can use the `new()` constraint for that:

```
class MyClass<T, U>
    where T : Something
    where U : AnOperation<T>, new()
{
    public U GetAnOperationOfSomething()
    {
        U anOperation = new U();
        //...
        return anOperation;
    }
}
```

The `new()` constraint guarantees that `U` will have a public default constructor, which you can invoke.

Comment: What about interface case (see my answer), why it is valid for compiler?

Comment: @astef It has absolutely nothing to do with class or interface. The key thing you do differently is that you create the instance in another method, so the  compiler dosen't know that the object is not an `U`. It will still fail in runtime, if you create an instance of `AnOperation<T>`. Keep the instantiation in a separate method and constrain it to a class instead of an interface. It will work.

Comment: Well, the constraints are wrong. You define `U : IAnOperation<Something>`. It should be `IAnOperation<T>`. Then class and interface act the same. An interface might have a relaxed compiler evaluation, in runtime it's just the same.

Comment: Yeah, the same. Except there's no runtime for not compiled code.

Comment: Dude, just try it out. **Set the right constraint** and make it a class.

Comment: I'm not asking about fixing the code. I'm asking why replacing `interface` to `class` in my answer's sample makes code not compiling. Your first version with method is wrong. Your second version - "relaxed compiler evaluation" is too broad. Nevermind, you just don't know, as am I

Comment: Because (as I said) an interface is not a class and is evaluated differently by the compiler (since an object can only derive from one class, but implement multiple interfaces). It will fail at runtime just the same, since then only what the object *is* counts, not what it *could be*.

Answer (score 5):

`T` in your class is any class inheriting from `Something`.
`U` is any class inheriting from `AnOperation<Something>`. Suppose you have child class like this:

```
public class ChildOperation<T> : AnOperation<T> {}
```

Now your `U` might be `ChildOperation<Something>`, and you cannot return instance of parent class (`AnOperation<T>`) as instance of child class (`U` which is `ChildOperation<Something>`). It might also go wrong when `T` is really `ChildSomething`, because `AnOperation<Something>` cannot be implicitly converted to `AnOperation<ChildSomething>`. Long story short - `AnOperation<T>` indeed cannot be always converted to your `U` type, so compiler is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just to support @Evk's answer. See this example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass<SomeSomething, AnOperation<Something>> foo = 
        new MyClass<SomeSomething, AnOperation<Something>>(); 
        // AnOperation<SomeSomething> will cause a compile error.

        var bar = foo.GetAnOperationOfSomething();

        Console.WriteLine(bar != null);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class MyClass<T, U>
    where T : Something
    where U : AnOperation<Something>
{
    public U GetAnOperationOfSomething()
    {
        U anOperation = Activator.CreateInstance<U>();

        return anOperation;
    }
}

public class Something
{
}

public class AnOperation<T>
    where T : Something
{
}

public class SomeSomething : Something
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It surprisingly compiles if you switch from `AnOperation` class to `IAnOperation` interface:

```
class MyClass<T, U>
    where T : Something
    where U : IAnOperation<Something>
{
    public U GetAnOperationOfSomething()
    {
        IAnOperation<T> anOperation = GenAnOperation();
        return (U)anOperation;
    }

    private IAnOperation<T> GenAnOperation()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Something
{ }

public interface IAnOperation<T>
    where T : Something
{ }
```

Comment: While it compiles - it's not type safe, becase your `(U)anOperation` cast can fail at runtime. Also you did not use any type parameters variance here (though it won't help anyway).

Comment: @Evk Agree. Can you explain, why it compiles for interface but not class? Feel free to edit my answer, it would be helpful not only for OP

Comment: Hard to provide exact explanation, but in general compiler cannot be so sure about whether cast is possible when interface is involved, because actual type behind that interface can be anything, and that type can be castable to target type. With concrete types like in OP example compiler has much more information and so in many cases might figure out types are unrelated to each other and refuse the cast at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do, you may want  to expand the question. For instance, will there be several types of operation? Depending on that there are several possible solutions

If there are no operation subtypes, the U parameter is unnecessary. Just return `AnOperation<T>` as that can already describe all operations.

```
    // With only one type of operation
    namespace ConsoleApp2
    {    

        class MyClass<T> where T : Something        
        {
            public AnOperation<T> GetAnOperationOfSomething()
            {
                AnOperation<T> anOperation = new AnOperation<T>();
                return anOperation; 
            }
        }

        public class Something
        {
        }

        public sealed class AnOperation<T>
            where T : Something
        {
        }
    }
```

If there are many kinds of operations (which seems likely), then the problem is that your class can't know about how to make them when it doesn't know about them. You need to give your class a function that can produce an `U` instance to return.

```
    // With a factory for operations
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {    
        class MyClass<T, U>
            where T : Something
            where U : AnOperation<Something>
        {
            private readonly Func<T, U> operationMaker;

            public MyClass(Func<T, U> operationMaker)
            {
                this.operationMaker = operationMaker;           
            }

            public U GetAnOperationOfSomething(T something)
            {           
                U anOperation = operationMaker(something);
                return anOperation; 
            }
        }

        public class Something
        {
        }

        public class AnOperation<T>
            where T : Something
        {
        }

    }
```

Alternatively you can constrain `U` to new `new()` so that your class can create them without further knowledge.

```
    // With a "new()" contraint on U
    namespace ConsoleApp3
    {    
        class MyClass<T, U>
            where T : Something
            where U : AnOperation<Something>, new()
        {
            public U GetAnOperationOfSomething()
            {           
                U anOperation = new U();
                return anOperation; 
            }
        }

        public class Something
        {
        }

        public class AnOperation<T>
            where T : Something
        {
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the following works for me (EDIT: I am in framework v4.5.2):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass<Something, AnOperation<Something>> obj = new MyClass<Something, AnOperation<Something>>();
        }
    }

    class MyClass<T, U>
        where T : Something
        where U : AnOperation<Something>
    {
        public U GetAnOperationOfSomething()
        {
            AnOperation<T> anOperation = new AnOperation<T>();

            return anOperation as U;

        }
    }

    public class Something
    {
    }

    public class AnOperation<T>
        where T : Something
    {
    }
```

Comment: did you run it? the `as` operator will return `null` if the cast is unsuccessful

Comment: Yes it might - but then there is slim possibility for it as the constraint on U forces the type compatibility. so you really cant replace anything which is not a subtype of Something/

Comment: If there are no subtypes of AnOperation<T> then the U parameter was unnecessary to begin with, and if there are subtypes of AnOperation (So the caller does `new Myclass<Something, SubOperation<Something>>` then the class will always return null.